# Facebook API events.invite method error 114?

Tags: php, curl, facebook

I'm getting this error when I try and invite people to my event: 114 must be a valid ID string (e.g., "123") method events.invite ...

Here is my php5 code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.facebook.com/home.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Firefox/3.5");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ . "/cookie-jar/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . "/cookie-jar/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.facebook.com/login.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=".urlencode($this->USERNAME)."&pass=".urlencode($this->PASSWORD));
    curl_exec($ch);
    sleep(10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $URL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/events.invite";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);

    $POST_FIELDS = "eid=$EID&uids=$UIDS&access_token={$this->TOKEN}";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_FIELDS);
    $events = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($events);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The code is hard to read but I think it is because you are trying to set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` twice on the same `curl` handler. Try closing the `curl` handler after the first request.